# Issue with creating log in production mode using Rails Logger

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, apache, ruby-on-rails-4, testing, passenger

I hosted my Rails 3.2.13 application in (Ubuntu 14.04 + Passenger + apache2) combination server.

Everything is working perfect in development environment; but in production environment. I got error like below :-

In browser

```
We're sorry, but something went wrong.
We've been notified about this issue and we'll take a look at it shortly.
```

Than, I decided to take log report in `log/production.log` and done some changes like below.

In `/config/environments/production.rb` file:

```
config.consider_all_requests_local = true
config.log_level = :debug
Rails.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
Rails.logger = Log4r::Logger.new("Application Log")
```

Even than, log report is not created in `/log/production.log` file

Do I need to do anything else ? kindly someone assist me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Did you see this http://serverfault.com/questions/393716/where-do-passenger-logs-go

Answer (score 1):

Passenger author here. In addition to the Rails log file, you should also look in the web server error log. Learn more about this in [the Passenger documentation's troubleshooting section.](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/admin/apache/troubleshooting/ruby/#check-the-passenger-log-file)